# QDateEdit return to previous state on button click in Qt C++

Tags: qt

I have a `QDateEdit` in a form in Qt and I want that on a button click this `QDateEdit` returns to its previous state. How can this be done?

Comment: You save its value whenever necessary, connect a `SLOT` to the button trigger and set the saved value

Comment: how to save its value?

Answer (score 0):

At any moment the state of a `QDateEdit` (which is actually a specialized `QDateTimeEdit`) can be retrieved by calling its [`date()` method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatetimeedit.html#date-prop).

Then, as was already said, you need to put this value into a `QDate` variable of your class and then create a slot which you connect to the button click and which then calls `setDate` to set the `QDateEdit` back to this date.

Below is a code snippet which shows one way to do this.

```
#ifndef MYDIALOG_H
#define MYDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QDateEdit>
#include <QPushButton>

class Dialog: public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT

    public:
  Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0) : QDialog(parent),
    layout(this),
    edit(),
    button("Reset",this)
      {
        layout.addWidget(&edit);
        layout.addWidget(&button);
        date = edit.date();
        connect(&button, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( resetTime() ) );
      }

  public slots:

  void resetTime()
  {
    edit.setDate(date);
  }

 private:

  QHBoxLayout layout;
  QDateEdit edit;
  QPushButton button;
  QDate date;

};

#endif
```

**main.cc** for completeness

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "dialog.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  Dialog dialog;

  dialog.show();

  return app.exec();

}
```

Let me know if this helps.